# Construction initializing the arguments in the constructor

Tags: c++

I have a simple yet maybe stupid question. I was asked to point out the difference between two initializing ways. I am not really able to point out the difference. Could you help me?

```
A(int a);
A(int a=3);
```

Comment: The one with a default value also counts as a *default constructor*.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `A` is a `class` or `struct`, then:

```cpp
A(int a);
```

defines a [*converting constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) that *requires* the caller to provide an input value when creating an object instance of `A`, eg:

```cpp
A a(12345); // OK
A a;        // ERROR
```

Whereas:

```cpp
A(int a=3);
```

defines a *converting constructor* that has a *default* parameter value, allowing the caller to omit passing in a value if desired, eg:

```cpp
A a1(12345); // OK, will use a=12345
A a2;        // OK, will use a=3
```

Since passing in an input value is optional in this constructor, it can thus also serve as `A`'s [*default constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) as well, unless one is also defined, then this becomes ambiguous as to which constructor to call when no input value is provided, eg:

```cpp
A();
A(int a = 3);
```

```cpp
A a; // ERROR, ambiguity
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first one you must provide the constructor an `int`.

```cpp
A(int a);
```

In the second you can provide an `int`, but if you don't the default value for `a` will be `3`.

```cpp
A(int a = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A(int a);
A(int a=3);

We can't declare the above constructor declaration together in the class.

Because compiler will say function already defined.

A(int a); is equal to A(int a=3);

For example if you have one constructor like as follows

A(int value=3) { a = value; cout << "\nOne Parameter Constructor" << " a="<<a; }

Object Creation:

A a1; A a2(6);

Output:

One Parameter Constructor a=3
One Parameter Constructor a=6